# Rewrite system.uri string from wpf to winui standard

Tags: image, xaml, embedded-resource, winui-3

I have png image in the Assets\NavImages\ folder in my WPF Assembly - EhLib.WPF.

And I refer to this file in the Image.Source line as follows.

```
          <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/EhLib.WPF;component/Resources/NavImages/DataNavigator_First.png"
                 Stretch="None" />
```

Now I port my Assembly to WinUI and try to use next line .

```
          <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/NavImages/DataNavigator_First.png"
                 Stretch="None" />
```

to refer to the similar file in the new Assembly - EhLib.WinUI.

But it doesn’t work.

The picture is not displayed.

This only works when the file is located in the main assembly of the executive application.

I can't find any useful information in the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.image.source?view=winui-3.0#microsoft-ui-xaml-controls-image-source

Answer (score 1):

This works only if you set the **Build Action** of the image to `Content` and copy it to the output folder:

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///ClassLibrary1/Assets/NavImages/DataNavigator_First.png"
       Stretch="None" />
```

I am afraid that embedded resources cannot be extracted using the `ms-appx` URI scheme. You will have to extract these programmatically yourself.

Comment: Build Action for images are Content. 
Source="ms-appx:///EhLib.WinUI/Assets/NavImages/DataNavigator_First.png"
works. Thanks.